# Firebase/Database + Radial Btn + JS

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a form using firebase to host and to get the form's data. Everything was fine when I realised.. my radio buttons are not getting the "corret" data. I mean, it doesn't matter if I select the first, second or third option, because in firebase it shows me the data of all 3 of them.

Here's my code and here's what I'm getting as a response:

HTML

```
<pre>
<form id="cfs_form">
<p>
  <label>Escolha o formato da apresentação:</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="lab1h" checked id="lab1h"> Laboratório hands on (1h de duração)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="lab1h30" id="lab1h30"> Laboratório hands on (1h30 de duração)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="techSession" id="techSession"> Sessão técnica demonstrativa (30 minutos)<br>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Título da sessão ou laboratório</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required><br>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Descrição. Favor detalhar o conteúdo apresentado, incluindo as soluções que serão exploradas. <br> Considere também convidar um cliente ou parceiro para dividir sobre implementação da solução.</label><br><br>
  <textarea rows="7" cols="57" name="descrp" form="cfs_form" id="descrp" placeholder="Escreva..." required></textarea><br>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Qual a audiência foco (ex: arquiteto de infra, desenvolvedor, cientista de dados e etc)</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="focusAud" id="aud" required><br>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Nome do Palestrante</label><br>
   <input type="text" name="spkrName" id="name" required><br>
  </p>
<p>
  <label>E-mail do Palestrante</label><br>
   <input type="email" name="spkrEmail" id="email" required><br>
  </p>
<p>
<label>Infraestrurura necessária (Ex: internet banda larga, máquinas virtuais, etc)</label><br>
   <textarea rows="7" cols="57" name="infra" id="infra" placeholder="Detalhe aqui." required></textarea><br>
</p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="cfs_form" required>

</form>

</pre>
```

JS

```
<pre>

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCBdMlSJKBNafROhSHy3KC_NWT86Uy1bRk",
    authDomain: "call-for-speakers-tnl.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://call-for-speakers-tnl.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "call-for-speakers-tnl",
    storageBucket: "call-for-speakers-tnl.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "537174530738",
    appId: "1:537174530738:web:367a659c4c03bf28e487ab",
    measurementId: "G-84V245HDZX"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');

//listen for form submit
document.getElementById('cfs_form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

//submit form
function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
 var title = getInputVal('title');
 var name = getInputVal('name');
 var email = getInputVal('email');
 var lab1h = getInputVal('lab1h');
 var lab1h30 = getInputVal('lab1h30');
 var techSession = getInputVal('techSession');
 var descrp = getInputVal('descrp');
 var aud = getInputVal('aud');
 var infra = getInputVal('infra');

//save message
 saveMessage(title, name, email, lab1h, lab1h30, techSession, descrp, aud, infra);

}

//function to get form values
function getInputVal(id){
 return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

//save message to firebase 
function saveMessage(title, name, email, lab1h,
lab1h30, techSession, descrp, aud, infra){
 var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
 newMessageRef.set({
 title: title,
 name: name,
 email: email,
 lab1h: lab1h,
 lab1h30: lab1h30,
 techSession: techSession,
 descrp: descrp,
 aud: aud,
 infra: infra
 });

alert("Cadastro feito com sucesso");

}
```

And the picture of how I'm getting the data.

I appreciate any help you can give me!